# How can i customise mapview's map marker popup like the image below in kivy?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

[MapMarker Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCsej.png)

I am trying to customise a MapMarker Popup without using the regular 'source' property in kivy MapView class. I have tried creating the circle with the button effect and elevation effect, but I can't seem to remove the white box background behind the red circle, and adding text in the circle also eludes me. Any idea would really help. I have included my simple test code sample.

Here is my py code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import (CircularRippleBehavior, FakeCircularElevationBehavior, BackgroundColorBehavior)
from kivy.garden.mapview import MapMarkerPopup, MapMarker
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior


class RoundedMarker(MDFloatLayout,
                MapMarkerPopup,
                CircularRippleBehavior,
                FakeCircularElevationBehavior,
                BackgroundColorBehavior,
                ButtonBehavior):
    pass

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"
        return Builder.load_file('test.kv')

TestApp().run()
```

And my kv code:

```
<RoundedMarker>:
size_hint: None,None
size: "20dp","20dp"
radius: self.size[0] / 2
md_bg_color: 1, 0, 0, 1

MapView:
    lat: 10
    lon: 10
    zoom: 5
    RoundedMarker:
        lat: 12
        lon: 12
        elevation: 5
```

Comment: check this tuto i uploaded recently https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obVJZFixGts

Comment: Thanks @Oussama. I saw your video during my research before asking the question here. It is not the popup itself that i am trying to customise, but the pin as is in your case. And like i said, i don't want to use the source property, instead i want to create it dynamically with kivy. Can you run my code, and you will get an idea of what i am trying to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also did not find a nice solution for removing the "source" argument.

I just created a PNG-image with one transparent pixel. The transparent pixel is than load with the source argument of add.mapmarkerpopup. As the image is now transparent you can add any Forms eg. with canvas. The image does not disturb anymore.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).